# Can't connect to a local IP cam from iPad, while connecting from a PC works

Tags: wireless-networking, ipad

Both my laptop and my iPad are on the same wireless network. `http://foscam1` comes up just fine on the laptop, or any other PC in the house. The iPad only connects about half the time. The other half it doesn't load the page.

The only odd thing about my home network, is that I have two wireless routers, using the same network name, but utilizing different channels. Could this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

(To be completely sure: does it make difference when using different browsers?)

It seems like your ipcam is random connected to router 1 or 2. Try ping from the pc to foscam1; Wait for a moment that the iPad don't loads the page. Now do a tracert to the ip of the ipcam from the pc. A tracert indicates all the nodes on the way to the given destination. After that do a tracert from the ipad; use a app like https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/nice-trace-traceroute/id322722672?mt=8. Now try again when the page loads correctly on the IPad. Compare the both results of a tracert when loading or not on both pc and IPad.